# How to right an if statement then add this number

Tags: excel

Im having trouble with a simple excel equation I need it to do this If E23 is equal to or greater then 25000 then add O4

Is this possible if so, I need to know how to do that one then add in the function 3 more times if same thing but for values 30000, 40000 and 50000

thank you in advance

Comment: I'm unclear what you want the result to be. Please post what you've tried, what you get and what you want.

Comment: What cell is this formula going into? (say B5 or whatever)?  Then for "3 more times" what cell(s) does that go into? (B5 or elsewhere( B6, B7 B8))? Adding in always O4, or 3 other locations?   We NEED much more specific info.  Please write it as arithmetic statement(s) using cell names.

Comment: Do you need an Excel formula for this or would VBA be ok as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you want to add but the following formula should get you there;

`=IFERROR(IFS($E$23>=50000,$E$23+$O$4,$E$23>=40000,$E$23+$O$4,$E$23>=30000,$E$23+$O$4,$E$23>=25000,$E$23+$O$4),"")`

Replace `E23+O4` with what you want your result to be if that is not it.

Comment: Okay SO this is even closer this at least gives me the correct rolling function now what I need it to do is to add each one retro so at 25000 its 500 at 30000 its 1000 at 40000 its 2000 at 50000 its 3000 and at 60000 its 4000, although now that im writing this it may be more beneficial to just change the value for 60000 from its individual value to the rolled value

Comment: It's still not at all clear what you want as an end result. Please read this guide on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So your original script worked flawlessly, now I have a new problem I had to create a new true value space for it because I cannot put this script behind the =SUM(K2:K22) and i dont know how to post a picture otherwise this would seem very trivial =IFERROR(IFS($E$23>=60000,$K$23+$O$7,$E$23>=50000,$K$23+$O$6,$E$23>=40000,$K$23+$O$5,$E$23>=30000,$K$23+$O$4,$E$23>=25000,$K$23+$O$3),"") the only problem is I cant tack it behind =SUM(K2:K22) it gives me an error

Comment: You can add an image like this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post. From what what I can understand you want to put these formula in the same cell? In that case change each instance of $K$23 to SUM(K2:K22).

Comment: Note that if you want to drag this cell down and have the results apply to other rows (e.g. K3) you should remove the `$` sign before the number (e.g. `$K2` rather than `$K$2`

Comment: So changing the instance does infact work and do most of what i need it to, however it only applies a value after the target reaches 25k if the target is under 25k it does not apply the lower values and Can i just email it to you work dosnt allow for imgur and I cant make heads or tails of how to upload an image of a data table

Comment: Replace the final `""` with SUM(K2:K23) and it will return the sum for instacnes below 25000

Answer (score 0):

So, for the first question try:

```
=IF(E23>=25000,E23+O4,0)
```

You can change the values as you wish now.

Comment: This is really close to what I am needing I think the problem is i have to much going on but this is very very close. So let me give more detail. Im in sales and everydeal i do make a gross profit when that gross profit reachs 25K I get a 500$ bonus so I put each deal in and then it rolls the gross into total, and then it rolls it further in a different column for how much each deal pays then it rolls it down into total gross payable to me so that being said I have =SUM(K2:K22) built into K23 what i need is to add after =SUM(K2:K22) =IF(E23>=25000,K23+O4,0)etc and so on but this is very close

Comment: Well give a decent explanation of what you want to calculate because I don’t follow. How about a table with the corresponding values and examples.

Comment: Stupid question but can I post a table and the answer you gave actually worked very well I ended up using this =IFERROR(IFS($E$23>=60000,$K$23+$O$7,$E$23>=50000,$K$23+$O$6,$E$23>=40000,$K$23+$O$5,$E$23>=30000,$K$23+$O$4,$E$23>=25000,$K$23+$O$3),"") the only problem is I cant tack it behind =SUM(K2:K22) it gives me an error

Answer (score 0):

You could use a VBA function for this.

```
Public Function DoSomething(cell1 As Variant, cell2 As Variant) AS Variant
    If IsNumeric(cell1) = False OR IsNumeric(cell2) = False Then
        DoSomething = ""
        Exit Function
    End If

    If cell1 >= 25000 Then
        DoSomething = cell1 + cell2
        Exit Funtion
    ElseIf cell1 >= 30000 Then
        'Do something different
    ElseIf cell1 >= 40000 Then
        'Do something different
    ElseIf cell1 >= 50000 Then
        'Do something else
    Else
        DoSomething = ""
        Exit Function
End Function
```